# Can I make a Sandbox meta post instead of using the normal Sandbox?

Tags: discussion, sandbox

My next challenge will rely heavily on Stack Snippets and http://api.stackexchange.com/ to gather data from the answers (similar to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/45040/user-scored-code-golf-drawing-diamonds-experimental) or [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/41462/a-different-kind-of-meta-regex-golf)).

I want to [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) it to iron out any kinks, but none of the data gathering will work if I answer in the normal Sandbox because answers can't have answers.

Could I (or anyone in this situation) make an entire question on Meta that is the Sandboxed challenge? Then I can add some answers and make sure the Stack Snippet works. I would delete it after I post the real challenge.

Comment: Self-deletion might be problematic if anyone else adds an answer, but I guess you could flag it for mod deletion in that case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If it's a temporary thing, I don't mind. It's probably not ideal, because we don't want to clutter meta with stuff like this, but I also don't see a good alternative. For past challenges (like the one you've linked), I've usually written my snippets based on similar existing questions, but knowing you I doubt that there is such a thing as a "similar existing question". ;)

(And I guess the votes on this answer will tell you if people agree with me or not. ;))

Comment: Yeah, I have been using other questions, but having a few answers that actually work with my snippet is necessary for thorough testing.